# Time complexity of nested loop with multiplication?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I just confused about to find out time complexity of the this nested loop:

```java
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    i*=2;
    for (int j=0; j<i; j++){
    }
}
```

And also what is the time complexity of the outer loop (just ignore the inner loop:

```java
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    i*=2;
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I ran the following code which is a modified version of the second code from the question.

```js
let it = 0
let pow = 1000
let n = Math.pow(2, pow)
for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    it++
    i *= 2
}
console.log(it)
```

It prints the value of either `pow+1` or `pow`, which implies that it runs log<sub>2</sub>(n) loops.

Although it contains a single for loop, it modifies iterating variables inside the loop. In every iteration, the value of `i` is doubled, which halves the remaining number of iterations. So instead of `O(n)`, it is `O(log n)`. It is similar to binary search if it helps you to understand better. In every iteration, it halves the remaining search space.

However, for the first code, it is quite confusing. Since the outer loop runs for log<sub>2</sub>(n) times, and the inner loop runs `i` times which is dependent on `n`. My guess is for the first code, big O notation is `O(n log(n))`. But for this case, my guess is as good as yours.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I also was thinking O(logn) for the second code. For the first code answer says it is O(n)?

Comment: Hmm, it is quite intriguing. Could you please share it with me? @monstereo